# Como utilizar itens de varios componentes em apenas um no angular4

Tags: node.js, aplicação-web, angular

Tenho um template que forma um formulario de cadastro, ele está separado em três components "Usuario, Nota, Endereço" os três estão sendo renderizado, mas não consigo acessar o conteudo deles ao submeter o formulario. Preciso que os campos dos fomularios sejam todos enviados ao submeter o formulario mas não sei exatamente como o fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se estes valores estão salvos no banco de dados, seria interessante usar um Service para receber esses valores no component do formulário.

Caso seja entre os components, poderia utilizar os `@Input` e `@Output`.

Dê uma olhada neste video, talvez te ajude.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I317BhehZKM